# Check time from mysql database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, timezone

I have two times in mysql DB start 10:00 and end 18:00 now i want to check with PHP if time is not greater or less of this two times how to do it? Thanks Mysql is set to TIME only no datetime, basically i want to check if time now is not between  start and end. start represent = from2 and end represent to2. Day_id is week day .this is what is not working

```
$time_now = date("H:i");
//in DB format 00:00 // time
echo "SELECT * FROM opening_hrs WHERE 
        (TIME(from2) > TIME('".$time_now."')  AND TIME(to2) < TIME('".$time_now."') )
        AND day_id=".$day_id;
```

any ideas how to check time("H:i"); between to times from DB?

Comment: No need to import time from PHP, MySQL has a `NOW()` function to use current time.

Comment: Side note: don't build queries by directly concatenating the parameters, it makes you open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work). You should use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: Is this correct: "*i want to check if time now is not between start and end*"? Your query is doing the exact opposite.

Comment: How i can use NOW() if server id in US and website is in AU?

Comment: well thanks for comment "El_Vanja" so a want to only check if time now is between times in DB eg: 12:00 and 16:00 do you have any example?

Comment: Check the answer, it has all the necessary details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query, using MySql's notion of the current time.

```
SELECT * FROM opening_hrs 
 WHERE TIME(NOW()) >= TIME(from2)
   AND TIME(NOW()) < TIME(to2)
   AND day_id=whatever
```

**Pro tip** Be careful to use `>=` for the beginning of time ranges and `<` for their ends, to avoid [off-by-one](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/506010907021828096?s=21) errors.

`NOW()` is a time zone sensitive operation in MySql. If you do this right after you open each MySql connection. you'll get your local time from `NOW()`.

```
SET time_zone = `Australia/Sydney`;
```

Obvs, use your own [time zone designator](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Comment: I have set up date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');

Comment: do i need something else? in php set ot in php.ini?

Comment: I gave you a pure-MySql way to do your query. For my answer to work for you, no changes to your php configuration are required. I corrected an error in your query pointed out by @El_Vanja, where you had the beginning and end of your range swapped (i've made that mistake countless times).

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `current_time`, which is a MySQL built-in that gives you the current time:

```
select * 
from opening_hrs 
where 
    current_time >= time(:from2)   
    and current_time < time(:to2)
    and day_id = :day_id
```

Note that you should be using prepared statements rather than concatenating variables into the query string: more about this in [this famous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/10676716).